Error generating Mocks with @GenerateNiceMocks annotation flutter dart
I am trying to Mock a class with @GenerateNiceMocks, when I setup @GenerateNiceMocks and tried to build the generated files I encountered following problem.
Invalid @GenerateMocks annotation: Mockito cannot generate a valid mock 
class which implements 'CLASS TO MOCK' for the following reasons:

The property accessor 'CLASS.VARIABLE=' features a private parameter type, '_ANOTHERCLASS', and cannot be stubbed. 
Try generating this mock with a MockSpec with 'unsupportedMembers' or a dummy generator (see 
https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/annotations/MockSpec-class.html).

Following is replica of my code:
class CLASSTOMOCK {
    late final _ANOTHERCLASS classVariable;

    CLASSTOMOCK(){
        classVariable = _ANOTHERCLASS();
    }
}

I have tried with all the options of Mocking like @GenerateMocks, @GenerateNiceMocks and creating a new class by extending Mock and implementing CLASSTOMOCK. But no luck.
I am also using unsupportedMembers option in @GenerateNiceMocks but it's not working properly.
Thank you in advance for helping me.

The error message tells you what's wrong: the class you're trying to mock has a member variable that depends on a private type (_ANOTHERCLASS).  Mockito cannot generate anything for a class it has no access to.  The error message also gives instructions for what to do; did you try following them?

@jamesdlin Yes, I tried adding "unsupportedMembers" option in the MockSpec(). But it's still not working and error is still there. Tried all the options in the MockSpec() unsupportedMembers.

@jamesdlin For reference:
@GenerateNiceMocks([
MockSpec(unsupportedMembers: {#annotations,
#_AnnotationManager, #AnnotationManager}),
])

@jamesdlin By the way, Issue has been resolved now.
Consider github issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/774
